# index.html file Style background img url for python Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

```
style="background-image:url({% static 'images/home_slider.jpg' %})"
```

Please see the above code and correct me if i am wrong. This code is for loading background img in django using static load method.

It is showing error in vs code.
Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

yes.no need to write like this.just write:

```
.mydiv{
  background: url('<your_image_path>');
}
```